# What does "$A_{ij}$ are two by two independent but not mutually independent" mean"?

Tags: probability

I'm doing this exercise in probability class:

> [image]

I could not understand what *$A_{ij}$ are two by two independent but not mutually independent* means. From my understanding, we talk about independence when we have at least two random variables. Clearly, $A_{ij}$ is an event, not a variable in this case.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Events can be dependent or independent.   Here, note that if we have, say, $A_{12}$ and $A_{23}$ then we automatically have $A_{13}$.  Thus the three events $A_{12},A_{23},A_{13}$ are certainly not mutually independent.

Comment: A nitpick: these events are not pairwise independent, because $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$ for all $i,j$. But we know what you mean :-)

Comment: I usually hear this called "pairwise independent", not "two-by-two independent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two events $A,B$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. So you must show that $P(A_{ij}\cap A_{i'k'})$ breaks up into a product whenever $i\neq i'$ and $j\neq j'$. However $P(A_{12}\cap A_{13}\cap A_{23})$ doesn't factor.

Comment: Did you mean $P(A_{12}\cap A_{13} \cap A_{23})$ by $P(A_{12}\cap A_{13}A_{23})$? The notation $P(A_{12}\cap A_{13}A_{23})$ seems strange to me ;(

Comment: yep,  that's what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a little and found this
"The concept of independence extends to dealing with collections of more than two events or random variables, in which case the events are pairwise independent if each pair are independent of each other, and the events are mutually independent if each event is independent of each other combination of events."
And I guess when it says to show that Aij are two by two independent but not mutually independent is for every i and j such that Aij makes sense